# How to add a body class

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following piece of code in my functions.php file. What i want to do is to add one more attribute (let's say — "extraclass") to my shortcode [template]. Attribute's value should be the name of the extra class and I want my code to add this class to the body tag. I know about the add_filter function, i've tried to use it but didn't succeed.

```
function templatefn($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "content" => ""
    ), $atts));

    ob_start();
    get_template_part('content', $content);
    $ret = ob_get_contents();  
    ob_end_clean();  
    return $ret;   
}
add_shortcode('template', 'templatefn');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Within your template if you are using the function [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) to give the body element different css classes (based on your current page for conditional styling) you should then be able to [filter this using the examples listed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) to achieve your outcome.

Comment: OP said that add_filter is not usable, is it not possible to implement this with a tag?